# "ENVIRONMENT" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js, environment-variables

I found this error when I run in next js.
The script text is
▷ Debug

"scripts": {

"dev: "ENVIRONMENT=env/.env.development next dev",
"check": "npm run format && npm run eslint", "eslint": "eslint --ext .jsx,.js components/ pages/",

"format":
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

NextJS has [built-in support](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) for loading env variables from `.env.local` and `.env.development`, so try to use that.

If you need to pass custom env file, at least you need to put the ENVIRONMENT argument after `next dev`, not before.